# head table values not duplicate

Tags: php

basically two table work i want to select one head value against its id collect all data from second table and than second head value against its id collect all data and ...... my problem is when collect value from head table and against its id collect all values from second table but head value repeated again and again against second table values in while loop

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
            FROM account_head
            LEFT JOIN account_head_name
            ON account_head.ID = account_head_name.account_head_ID ");
while($array=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($array > 0)
    {
        ?>

        <b><?php echo $array['Name'] ; ?> </b>
        <br>
        <?php echo $array['name'] ; ?>
        <br>

        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: group by your required values . and please draw the table structure also

Comment: Give the table structure of two tables

Comment: head table name 'account_head' there are two columns in it one is 'ID' and other is 'Name' and second table name account_head_name there four columns in it 'ID', 'account head ID','sub account ID' and  'name '

Comment: output                                                                                                   Inventory 
Sand 
Inventory 
iRON 
Cost of Sales 
abc 
Inventory 
glass 
Sales 

Suppliers 

Customers 

abc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one - many relation the best way to get data is make two queries

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
            FROM account_head");
while($array=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   ?>
       <b>Head Name:<?php echo $array['Name'] ; ?> </b>
   <?php 
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * 
            FROM account_head_name where account_head_ID = $array['ID'] ");
     while($array1=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    ?>


        <br>
        <?php echo $array1['name'] ; ?>
        <br>

        <?php
   }

}
```

Note: Better to avoid mysql function Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.